# change case unless it's a hyper link in python

Tags: python, string, case

What would be the easiest way to change a string, while preserving white space, changing every upper case letter to lower case except for links?

All the links start with 'http://' or 'https://'

An example would be:

```
HELLO     HOW ARE YOU  CHECK OUT THIS: http://sOme.Link THIS IS AWESOME
```

should change into:

```
hello     how are you  check out this: http://sOme.Link this is awesome
```

I tried .lower() which of course messes up the links. I thought about doing it word by word but that will mess up the white space.

So I am guessing there must be something like a 'sed' command but couldn't find it.

Comment: You have to provide what you have tried so far. We are here to __help__ not __do stuff for you__

Comment: added what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = string.split()

lower_words = []

for word in words:
    if word.startswith(('http:','https:')):
        lower_words.append(word)
    else:
        lower_words.append(word.lower())

print ' '.join(lower_words)
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer but wouldn't this change the white space if the string has consecutive blank characters?

Comment: @yam, True, but is that really necessary if you get: `"hello hi"` from `"hello   hi"`

Comment: @yam, I see. Give me a few more minutes to figure this out then. :)

Comment: For the A+ answer, include 'https:' too

Comment: @smci, Thank you for that, I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Hey actually, http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html: *prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.* So even more compactly: `if word.startswith(('http:','https:')):` . Yay, golf.

Comment: I never knew it took a tuple either! I was thinking it didn't take regex.

Answer (score 1):

I nearly pulled all my hair out on this one but I finally got it to work. Lowercase of non-links with spaces preserved:

```
string = 'HELLO HOW ARE      YOU CHECK OUT        THIS: http://sOme.Link THIS IS   AWESOME'

i=0
while i < len(string):
    try:
        end_i = i+string[i:].index(' ')
    except ValueError:
        end_i = len(string)
    if string[i:end_i].startswith(('http:','https:')):
        pass
    else:
        string = string[:i]+string[i:end_i].lower()+string[end_i:]
    i = end_i+1

print string
```

Hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case here I might use a regular expression to do the splitting:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "HELLO     HOW ARE YOU  CHECK OUT THIS: http://sOme.Link THIS IS AWESOME"
>>> parts = re.split("(\s+)", s)
>>> parts
['HELLO', '     ', 'HOW', ' ', 'ARE', ' ', 'YOU', '  ', 'CHECK', ' ', 'OUT', ' ', 'THIS:', ' ', 'http://sOme.Link', ' ', 'THIS', ' ', 'IS', ' ', 'AWESOME']
>>> ''.join(p.lower() if not p.startswith(('http:', 'https')) else p for p in parts)
'hello     how are you  check out this: http://sOme.Link this is awesome'
```

Or maybe go the other way split only on the links, but I tend to prefer writing in Python rather than writing regular expressions as much as possible.